# Preventing New line in a multiline text box

Tags: asp.net, javascript

How to prevent the new line character at the beginning of the text entering in a multiline text box? Now, I already trimmed the white space at the beginning of the text. but i can't  prevent the new line character that has to be occurred by entering the enter key on the most beginning of the text box. Please help me. thanks in advance.

Comment: You tagged your question with javascript. Do you want a javascript or .net solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Manged code:
yourText.Replace(Environment.Newline, String.Empty)

In JavaScript:
Have a look here this is what you are looking for http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-trim.html

```
function ltrim(str, chars) {
    chars = chars || "\\s";
    return str.replace(new RegExp("^[" + chars + "]+", "g"), "");
}
```

The following chars as parameters:

- “\n” (ASCII 10 (0×0A)), a new line
  (line feed).
- “\r” (ASCII 13 (0×0D)),
  a carriage return.

You can attach that to the OnChanged event of the textbox.